# Joomla onExtensionAfterSave event

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, plugin

I am developing a component extension to create different forms for insurance.

When I create a form in backend and save it by clicking the `Save` or `Save & Close` button, I am going to create a table in database. The suitable event could be `onExtensionAfterSave` event in a plugin belonging to group Extension.

Now the question is this: I saw two different samples of this method:

1. `onExtensionAfterSave($data, $isNew)`
2. `onExtensionAfterSave($context, &$table, $isNew)`

Which is the right one?

Also to obtain paremeters, Can I use `JPlugin::params` (params to my extension in the backend that are already created and saved to database)?

Comment: Is the component your component? If so why would you listen for your own events in a plugin rather than creating the tables within your component's controller?

Comment: The component is for creating forms with different fields and input, a form might be only one page or another one multi-pages, after creation of each form, a separate table will be created according to the  fields of created form. So I need to learn about the created forms field and input after it is created, the forms are quite different from each other and those forms will be used in site part, the created tables save the data to those forms after user input in the site part, created forms are not constant, they are dynamic, Events are necessary to learn about forms.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

onExtensionAfterSave isn't a common Joomla event - It only fires when the component/module/plugin configuration is saved.  Example, editing Joomla global configuration, editing the options of a component, editing the options of a module, editing the options of a plugin.  I've been writing extensions for years and I've never used that event - because it just isn't useful.

I think you picked the wrong event.

It won't fire on creating a form within your component unless you've written your component to fire that event.  And if you did, I'd suggest picking a different event - like onContentAfterSave, which is designed to do what you're asking for.

If it's your own component (that you're writing) - you might consider creating your own set of events to monitor. Joomla is designed to do this.  I did this in one of my own components to monitor a dozen different events related to CBT training.

When you're working with your own events, you can define whatever you want to send to the plugin.  In my events, most take only one variable - an ID.  The plugin retrieves the data based on that ID and does whatever it's designed to do.

Step 1, choose a unique type to name your plugin folder: /plugins/YOURNEWTYPE/

Step 2, make a test plugin to define and test your events.

Step 3, load the plugins and create a dispatcher in your component to fire your custom event whenever you need it.

It's super easy.

Comment: I considered custom event as  an alternative as long as I can use joomla events to get rid of dispatching of events separately in component, eg. plugin under group of content has no need to be dispatched separately in custom component. When the user saves component in back end, I got to create a table based on that form in which its inputs are not the same, the created form is  dynamic , so both onExtensionAfterSave and onContentAfterSave are able to handle it,  I will also develop a custom event plugin as you advised and I shall test all of them and may I ask what CBT training is?

Comment: About the example I said above in regard with joomla events plugin, I meant a plugin under group of search, I mentioned content mistakenly in the second line above.

Comment: I tried a test plugin, onExtensionAfterSave event did not work without being dispatched in controller, After I dispatched the event, it did and I have the id to be able to access the database to create my form. I used to create a plugin under search group, it worked without being dispatched, I expected the same here.

Comment: Sorry, but it is useful! Please don't denigrate it! It is the obvious hook to use in order to have an action as a result of someone changing something in the options. It's possible for an option to require processing to happen when it changes. The unfortunate issue is that the ComponentHelper::getParams() method still returns the old value during the onExtensionAfterSave processing, which makes it all much more difficult.

Comment: @mbrampton - you managed to immediately identify why I didn't find it useful.

Comment: @KianWilliamNowrouzian - CBT = Computer Based Training, basically any training you do on a computer or online can be classified as a CBT.  It's a very broad term.

Comment: @Michael That doesn't make it not useful. It's annoying that you have to do extra work to obtain the new information. But it's still helpful to be triggered at the correct time.

Comment: @mbrampton - yes, I'm quite aware of the extra work required, as can be found in my System - Software Log extension in the JED.  What I'm saying is that the event itself doesn't provide anything useful.  By itself, it isn't useful.  It requires extra work for it to become useful, unlike many of the other events which are useful out-of-the-box.

Comment: @Michael I don't know why you are arguing this. What you said in your answer was "I've never used that event - because it just isn't useful". That suggested that the event could be done away with. Now you're saying something different, and suggesting that you do in  fact make use of it. So far as I'm concerned, the event is absolutely essential. The defect we're agreed on is just an annoyance.

Comment: @mbrampton I wrote the answer 5 years ago, and wrote my extension 4 years ago.

Comment: Then why not amend your answer? Options are handled by Joomla without any involvement of the component. The ONLY way to know that options have changed is to create a plugin triggered by this event. Your original answer ignored this and implied that the event had no uses. If you subsequently changed your mind, then why not simply confirm these facts, and amend your answer?

Comment: No.  I'm not changing anything.  Get a life.

Answer (score 1):

The event is useful when you need custom code to be executed after saving an extension configuration. I use it in one of my templates to change favicon and logo when the color theme is changed.

```
onExtensionAfterSave($option, $data)
```

`$option` (string) where the plugin is called from. For a template this would be "com_templates.style".

`$data` (object) for a template this contains the matching row in table `#__template_styles` after saving, you can get the template params through `json_decode($data->params)`.